# $R \cong R[[x]]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Is it possible for a commutative ring with 1 to be isomorphic to the
>   power series ring over itself? $$R \cong R[[x]].$$ Bonus marks if you
>   can answer for $n$ variables more generally, $R \cong R[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$.

Obviously, $R$ would have to be huge (infinite Krull dimension). It's not clear to me that taking a colimit of iterates of the functor $S \mapsto S[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$ produces a ring of the desired kind, essentially because 
$$R[[x]][[y]] \not \cong R[[x,y]].$$
So you can't make a construction analogous to what's done for $R \cong R[X]$.

EDIT: Looks like I was under a misapprehension about the above-stated non-isomorphism. Thank you to several people for correcting this important mistake!

Comment: Bonus marks? Is this your homework?

Comment: No, was just being fun.

Comment: Thoughts: If you take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,...]$ (infinitely many variables). And then you add a new variable $y$ are they isomorphic by taking $y\mapsto x_1$ and $x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}$? If so that also proves the general case.

Comment: Bonus marks aren't enough. I'd like a gold star sticker, please.

Comment: @Yanko: Do you mean $R = \mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \dots]]$? If so, I think that fails due to the non-isomorphism I wrote. That is, $R[[x]]$ should still be strictly "bigger" than $R$.

Comment: Doesn't the zero ring satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I suppose it does! Thanks. I'm still interested in a less trivial example, or a proof that $R = 0$ is forced.

Comment: May be I'm dumb, but what is the difference between $R[[x]][[y]]$ and $R[[x,y]]$? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_in_several_variables) at least says that the topology on the former is usually chosen in such a way that the two rings are isomorphic as topological rings? Are you defining them with something other than as completions w.r.t. $I$-adic topology for the obvious ideal $I$? With countably infinitely many variables there may still be problems, so this is not necessarily relevant here :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was Martin Brandenburg's answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics which was in the back of my mind when I made my assertion... but maybe the non-isomorphism is just wrong ring-theoretically?

Comment: @Mr.Chip - If you answer a comment of mine, please add an `@Pierre-YvesGaillard`.

Comment: I think $R[[X_1,X_2,...]]$ works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M$ be a monoid which is "locally finite" by which we mean, for all $m\in M$, $\{(a,b)\in M\times M : ab =m \}$ is finite.

For such a monoid, for a ring $R$, we can make $R^M$ into a ring with the convolution product instead of $R^{\oplus M}$. Lets denote $R^M$ with the convolution product by $R[[M]]$. Now $R[[x]]=R[[\Bbb{N}]]$. Now observe that as sets, by the usual product-hom adjunction, $(R^M)^N = R^{M\times N}$. Moreover, if $M$ and $N$ are locally finite, then $M\times N$ is locally finite. Indeed, one can check that the preserves sums and products, so $R[[M]][[N]]\cong R[[M\times N]]$. Thus we just need to find a locally finite monoid $M$ such that $M\times \Bbb{N}\cong M$. An easy choice is 
$$M=\{u\in \Bbb{N}^\Bbb{N}:u_n\ne 0\text{ for only finitely many $n$}\}.$$
This is intuitively probably the monoid being referred to when people talk about $R[[x_1,x_2,\ldots]]$.

Thus this gives a proof outline that when $A=R[[x_1,x_2,\ldots]]$, then $A[[y]]\cong A$.

Comment: What's the difference with my answer?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard, detail

Comment: You gave a reminder of the definition of a formal power series, and I assumed that the reader was familiar with this notion. - Also, when you post an answer which merely adds a few details to an already existing answer, wouldn't it be better to state it explicitly?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, @Pierre-YvesGaillard and @jgon; I have +1'd both. At greater issue for me was proving $R[[x_1,x_2,\dots ]]$ works, which is why I have accepted this answer.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Sorry, initially I was responding on my phone, so I was a bit terse. When I was answering the question, the question already said "It's not clear to me that taking a colimit of iterates of the functor $S\mapsto S[[x1,…,xn]]$ produces a ring of the desired kind..." Thus your answer, which merely stated $A[[X_1,X_2,\ldots]]$ works didn't seem to provide anything useful, since the OP had already considered trying something of that sort, so the issue was either the OP wasn't sure such a thing existed or couldn't see how to show it worked.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard (continued) Thus I decided to add an answer explaining a construction and outlining a proof that it worked. I didn't reference your answer, because it didn't really inform my answer in a meaningful way, and at the time I didn't think it really answered the question. Also, in light of your edit adding details to your answer, I will also upvote it, as it does now provide another useful way to look at it.

Comment: @jgon - Thanks! I also upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 8):

As I said in the comments, the zero ring is a first example. Another example is $A[[X_1,X_2,...]]$ where $A$ is a commutative ring with one and the $X_i$ are indeterminates.

**Edit.** Here is a brief reminder.

If $A$ is a commutative ring with one, if $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of indeterminates, and if $M(I)\subset A[(X_i)_{i\in I}]$ is the set of monomials, then $A[[(X_i)_{i\in I}]]$ is the set of formal expressions of the form 
$$
\sum_{m\in M(I)}a_mm,
$$ 
with $a_m$ in $A$, equipped with its natural ring structure.

If $I=J\sqcup K$ is a partition of $I$, then the natural morphism 
$$
\left(A[[(X_j)_{j\in J}]]\right)[[(X_k)_{k\in K}]]\to A[[(X_i)_{i\in I}]]
$$ 
is easily seen to be an isomorphism.